# Not working redirect function in SCSDKLoginKit (snapchat)

Tags: ios, snapchat

I am trying to implement a Snapchat login button in my project. I have already downloaded the SDK, created a Snapchat developer account, and written some code in info.plist.

Right now I can sign into the Snapchat account, but when I click return to the app I get a 404 not found error page. I think the problem is in this function, because it doesn't work when I tap the back button:

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()?.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: "xxx", consumerSecret: "xxx")

    return true
}

  func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    if TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {return true}

    if FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {return true}

    if SCSDKLoginClient.application(app, open: url, options: options) {return true} // not work this func

    return true
}
```

In the case of Facebook or Twitter, there is one more function that makes them work when you enter the application, but in the case of Snapchat it does not exist.

I can't find any information about this in official Snapchat docs. 
What could the problem be?

Comment: did you find any solution? @viktor

Answer (score 0):

take anther look to info.list, it's very tricky, be sure that your SCSDKRedirectUrl the same in your snapchat app when i faced the same issue, the reason was that my SCSDKRedirectUrl's first character was capital letter and when i changed it to small letter everything was be okay 
i.e

```
<key>SCSDKRedirectUrl</key>
<string>yourAppName://auth/snap</string>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<string>yourAppName</string>
<array>
```